# Как связать bootstrap и drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, bootstrap

Как сделать связку bootstrap и drupal 7?
Предполагается создание адаптивного шаблона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://drupal.org/project/twitter_bootstrap ,
https://drupal.org/project/bh_bootstrap